# how to create a csh script that can identify the correct USB disk where I have saved my virtual machines

Tags: awk, sed, scripting, freebsd, csh

I'm running **Freebsd 13R** and as shell I'm using **csh**. I would like to create a script,that looks the presence of the word "**r1w1e2**" or "**NM13N4CZ**" or "**3e4d31334e34435a**" when I give the command "**geom disk list**" and it gives "**da3**" as output. I need this script because the mapping of my **USB** disks change often. But I need to identify with certainty what's the disk where I have stored all the *.img (virtual machines) files that I have created. For example,at the moment,when I give the command :

```
geom disk list :

Geom name: da3
Providers:
1. Name: da3
   Mediasize: 2000398933504 (1.8T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r1w1e2
   descr: Seagate M3 Portable
   lunname: NM13N4CZ
   lunid: 3e4d31334e34435a
   ident: NM13N4CZ
   rotationrate: unknown
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 255
```

I see that the correct disk is **da3**. So,I can start the VM I want with **bhyve** like this :

```
bhyve -S -c sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2 -m 8G -w -H -A \
-s 0,hostbridge \
-s 2,virtio-blk,/mnt/$disk$p2/bhyve/os/Linux/photon.img \
-s 3:0,passthru,1/0/0 \
-s 9,virtio-net,tap0 \
-s 10,virtio-9p,sharename=/ \
-s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5900,w=1440,h=900 \
-s 30,xhci,tablet \
-s 31,lpc \
-l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_BHF_CODE.fd \
-l com1,stdio \
vm0
```

like **$disk$** is **da3** and p2 never change. very thanks.

Solution :

solution :

```
set vmdisk=`geom disk list | awk '/^Geom name: /{d=$NF} /^ *lunname: (r1w1e2|NM13N4CZ|3e4d31334e34435a)/ && d{print d}'`

echo $vmdisk
da2

-s 2,virtio-blk,/mnt/$vmdisk'p2'/bhyve/os/Linux/photon.img \
```

Comment: Just because you're using `csh` doesn't mean your shell scripts also have to be written in `csh`. In fact, it's a terrible shell for writing scripts. Does it _really_ have to be a `csh` script?

Comment: Please, please do not write scripts in csh. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/548046/74393

Comment: Consider giving the partition a GPT label, and then you won't need to care what the device number is, you can reference the partition entirely by the GPT label you chose. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this makes two responders who aren't clear on what your purpose really is, but one of the main design goals of the `GEOM` layer is to avoid having to search through raw device nodes trying to find where your device went.  Your current method eschews all the device-agnostic advantages that using the `GEOM` layer affords.

Let's assume that your 2T USB drive has a `GPT` partition table.  If you apply a unique (and hopefully, descriptive) GPT label to partition 2 of that drive, you will be able to mount or reference the partition by that label, rather than being forced to figure out the correct (and ever-changing) `/dev/daNpM` device node.

First, figure out one last time, where your USB drive is.  Let's assume it's `/dev/da3`.  Here we'll label partition 2 on `da3` as `my-vm-partition`:

```
# gpart modify -l my-vm-partition -i 2 /dev/da3
```

Now you can:

```
# mount /dev/gpt/my-vm-partition /mnt
```

without having to know anything about the underlying `/dev/daN` device.

Or, if it's truly that Bhyve command line that's your end target, something like:

```
# mkdir /my-vm-partition
# mount /dev/gpt/my-vm-partition /my-vm-partition
# bhyve -S -c sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2 -m 8G -w -H -A \
-s 0,hostbridge \
-s 2,virtio-blk,/my-vm-partition/bhyve/os/Linux/photon.img \
-s 3:0,passthru,1/0/0 \
-s 9,virtio-net,tap0 \
-s 10,virtio-9p,sharename=/ \
-s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5900,w=1440,h=900 \
-s 30,xhci,tablet \
-s 31,lpc \
-l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_BHF_CODE.fd \
-l com1,stdio \
vm0
```

You may also want to take a look at Matt Churchyard's excellent `vm-bhyve` package and its ZFS integration.  Mounting filesystems by ZFS pool name or ZFS filesystem name would also save you all the hassle of trying to suss out the right device numbers from your `/dev` tree.

Comment: thanks for the good explanation on how the label works. You have explained well and now I can take it in consideration. Regarding the vm-bhyve wrapper,I'm not interested. I found it not useful at all,since I find more comfortable to play directly with the bhyve parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question, you would like to get the `Geom name` if **and only** `lunname` match one of the following : `r1w1e2`, `NM13N4CZ` or `3e4d31334e34435a`.
This `sed` should work (I can't test with `bsd sed`):

```
your_cmd | sed -n 's/^Geom name: \(.*\)$/\1/;ta;/^ *lunname: \(r1w1e2\|NM13N4CZ\|3e4d31334e34435a\)$/{g;p};d;:a h'
```

---

i'm pretty sure this awk will work :

```
your_cmd | awk '/^Geom name: /{d=$NF} /^ *lunname: (r1w1e2|NM13N4CZ|3e4d31334e34435a)$/ && d{print d}'
```

Comment: it works. do u know how can I save the value inside a variable that I can use with the  bhyve command ? the value should be copied here : -s 2,virtio-blk,/mnt/$diskp2/bhyve/os/Linux/photon.img \ ; where you see $disk

Comment: i'm not familiar with `csh`, but in a `POSIX` shell you can save the result of a command with the syntax : $(cmd).
So if `csh` let you do that you can save in that way: `disk=$(awk or sed cmd)`.

Comment: Nice observation @EdMorton , thanks!